# Tap target size not less than 48px for mobile Inbox (Google pagespeed)

Tags: wordpress, pagespeed

I am trying to optimize my website in Wordpress and running Google PageSpeed tells me the following about the table of contents in mobil:
"Tap target size not less than 48px for mobile Inbox".

The developer of the plugin told me to increase the pixels but the truth is that it looks ugly and too big. Any solution to this?

Solving the "Tap target size not less than 48px for mobile Inbox " problem

Comment: Hello. Any idea?

Comment: Google tries to warn you about a possible accessibility issue. You either follow their suggestions or you don't. What do you want us to do? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VjpcLplkMUs